# vlookup or index match to list names one below the other as an Array

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to list names below the other that satisfy a score. In my case it needs to be over 7, I am using `=INDEX($B$2:$B$16, SMALL(IF($E$2<=$C$2:$C$16, ROW($B$2:$B$16)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$16))+1, ""), ROW(A1)))` as an array.

The output im getting is getting stuck at Test2. What am I doing wrong. Is there an easier way to do this

[image]

Comment: First of all, your formula is performing a comparison with cell H2, though, based on your screenshot, shouldn't that be E2? Second, this clause: IF($H$2>=$C$2:$C$16,..., if you think about it, is actually looking to retrieve values in the range C2:C16 which are LESS than or equal to, not greater than or equal to, the value in H2. Third, since that is an array formula, have you remembered to commit it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: Thank you for that, Yup I changed the code to this `=INDEX($B$2:$B$16, SMALL(IF($E$2<=$C$2:$C$16, ROW($B$2:$B$16)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$16))+1, ""), ROW(A1)))` 

Now all i get is Test1

Comment: And what about the bit about committing as an array formula?

Comment: yes committed it as an array, im getting flower brackets displayed

Comment: Are you entering it as a SINGLE-CELL array formula, i.e. in cell G2 only, then dragging it down to G8? Or as a MULTI-CELL array formula, i.e. first selecting the range G2:G8, then entering that formula in the formula bar, followed by committing?

Comment: Im adding it as a multi cell formula, selecting the entire range and then committing, dragging it gives me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer a *single-cell* array-formula approach in such cases, i.e. via entering the appropriate array formula in cell `G2` only, then copying down as required.

If you were to do likewise, your current formula would work as required.

However, when entered as a *multi-cell* array formula, i.e. via first selecting the required range (e.g. `G2:G8`), then entering the formula in the formula bar followed by committing, the construction you are using for `SMALL`'s *k* parameter, i.e.:

`ROW(A1)`

will not be processed in a *row-relative* manner, as desired; in fact, for each instance of the formula, it will remain precisely as above, and not - as is the case when we copy down the equivalent single-cell version - update to, successively:

`ROW(A2)`

`ROW(A3)`

`ROW(A4)`

...

etc.

If you insist on continuing to use a multi-cell array formula here, you will need to use either the *unqualified* `ROW` for this parameter, i.e.:

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$16,SMALL(IF($E$2<=$C$2:$C$16,ROW($B$2:$B$16)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$16))+1,""),ROW()-1))`

or, since the above is not very robust, nor flexible (unqualified, `ROW()` is dependent upon the row in which the formula resides; hence, in your case, since your first formula is in row 2, we need to offset this value by -1), we can use the much better (though slightly longer):

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$16,SMALL(IF($E$2<=$C$2:$C$16,ROW($B$2:$B$16)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$16))+1,""),ROW($B$2:$B$16)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$16))+1))`

In any case, even for the single-cell version, `ROW` is a poorer choice than `ROWS` for generating incremental integers (https://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/), though sadly `ROWS` too is not an option for the multi-cell version, which is one of the reasons why I personally tend to prefer a series of single-cell array formulas over a single multi-cell one.

My personal preference would be the single-cell array formula:

`=INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($E$2<=$C$2:$C$16,ROW($B$2:$B$16)),ROWS($1:1)))`

and copied down, though I would also probably add a clause to mask errors in cells beyond the expected number of returns, e.g.:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>A$1,"",INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF($E$2<=$C$2:$C$16,ROW($B$2:$B$16)),ROWS($1:1))))`

where `A1` contains a formula to count the number of expected returns, e.g.:

`=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$16,">="&$E$2)`

which is preferable (and especially so over large ranges) to a resource-heavy `IFERROR` set-up (https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values).

And I should also say that I would use a slightly different version if the data being queried formed part of an Excel Table.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Xor, that really helped. If you used a single cell single-cell formula, what would your approach be? just curious to see how else you can do this

Comment: Added to the foot of the post.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! God bless.